# Distributed Keying / Partitioning / Sharding Java library

Tags: java, apache-kafka, distributed-computing, hazelcast, sharding

I receive http requests on my N fronend machines and want to have them processed by my K backend machines depending on a certain key in the data.
the keying has to be stable and consistent. I also want to scale the frontend and backend machines depending on the load without interruption. I am fine when very little data is lost while scaling.

I think i could achieve my goal with kafka or apache flink. Maybe also hazelcast could be used, by they all seem heavy weight and too much for my case.

Is there a library that just solves the aspect of keying / partitioning / sharding in a distributed way ?

Bonus points for rx integration library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this kind of scenario I usually use a cluster tech that tracks membership (hazelcast or my favorite jgroups, much lighter than hazelcast)

Then combine the current cluster size/members with a consistent hashing function like Guava's (see https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/HashingExplained )

The consistent hash would take in your data as the key and the current cluster member size as the buckets, and you would get back a consistent answer for that same # of buckets.

Then use the computed bucket to route your request

Answer (score 7):

What makes you think Hazelcast is heavier?

Hazelcast actually provides everything within a single environment - sharding, consistent hashing, partitioning and ensuring high availability of the data etc. Plus the easy and straightforward APIs take away lot of pains of writing code to use. All you are required to do is start a HC cluster using startup scripts and invoke APIs like map.put(key, value)/map.get(key) etc, its that simple as everything else is taken care of by Hazelcast behind the scenes.